# Occasional chain slipping/skipping - is it possible for the hub to be at fault?

Tags: shimano, chain, cassette

So I have this problem for a while now, at first I thought its badly indexed gears, worn chain, worn pulleys, bent hanger etc, etc. But after changing majority of stuff still have this slipping stuff.

It feels like chain jumps/slips every once in a while and I get like 1/4th circle of free spin on cranks.

So my question is, is it technically possible that the hub is at fault?

Since:

- Gears indexed well
- Shifts very well
- New chain
- New pulleys
- Derailleur good condition
- Rear cassette good condition (still pretty newish)
- Chainring good condition
- Hanger not bent
- Frame not bent

Had this problem with old chain too by the way.

Sram 1x11, sram nx x-sync chainring, kmc x11 chain, shimano deore xt derailleur, sram pg1130 cassete (11speed), shimano FH-RM35 hub (still stock, but bicycle was 11 gears stock too)

Comment: Have you made sure your cassette's tightened properly? Have had a chain seemingly slipping / jumping because of that before - it wasn't loose, just shifting a tiny bit under load. Tightening the cassette properly sorted it.

Comment: @Diado yeah, it wasn't tightened to the shimano/sram spec before, but I did few days ago after cleaning it up, problem still persist. It's not that it shifts, nor happens when shifting, it feels like chains links get placed wall up on the chainring before slipping hole onto teeth. Which is kinda unreasonable since it happens on all gears, even when chain is completely straight.

Comment: I had this kind of problem once with a chain I had to manually shorten out on the road and I had to re-use the same pin to close the chain.  The chain appeared fine, but that pin was a bit sticky, and after running through the derailleur pulleys it would sometimes hit the cassette with a few degrees of remaining bend that didn't pull out until it rolled around to the top and got the full tension of the chain.  At which point the chain would skip forward a link and reseat with a jolt.  Shouldn't be a problem with a new chain, but if you're out of ideas you could check...

Comment: Answering the question in the title, this appears to be a quick release hub, and I think it's possible that the hub might slip in the dropouts if the skewer isn't tightened enough. It would not produce the symptoms you described, however (and that's why this isn't an answer). I may suggest an edit to the title for clarity. As an aside, if this happens to you, I'd get an internal cam quick skewer. They generate more clamping force than external cam skewers. However, the stock Shimano QR should be internal cam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the hub can be at fault. The freewheel mechanism pawls may be sticking in the retracted position, or the pawls and teeth are worn and the pawls are slipping out of the teeth.

You can try to confirm this by having a friend ride behind and to the right of you and watch the cassette area (in an area free of obstructions where you can do this safely). They should be able to see if the cassette spins when the slip happens. If it does the hub is at fault.

Comment: Also it should be tested whether the slipping always happens at high pedaling forces on a certain sprocket or a certain number of sprockets. If it is so, the likely culprit is the cassette.